# can't get requirejs, angularjs and almond to work together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, requirejs, almond

I've been struggling with this all day, it seems like I'm the only one with this problem.

everything works perfectly before compiling and even by compiling without setting:

```
almond: true,
wrap: true,
```

And even with these settings grunt still works without an error. But angular never gets bootstrapped!
If I try to manually bootstrap it in the console through:

angular.bootstrap(document, ['wtvApp']);

It returns

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module wtvApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'wtvApp' is not available!
```

I would like to be able to serve a single file instead of:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

my grunt.js config: (some paths where removed to simplify)

```
requirejs: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: 'app/scripts',
      name: '../components/almond/almond.js',
      include: ['main.js'],
      out: 'dist/scripts/main.js',
      mainConfigFile: "app/scripts/main.js",
      optimize: 'uglify2',
      generateSourceMaps: true,
      preserveLicenseComments: false,
      useStrict: true,
      wrap: true,
      almond: true,
      findNestedDependencies: true
    }
  }
},
```

main.js

```
require.config({
paths: {
    jquery: '../components/jquery/dist/jquery',
    angular: '../components/angular/angular',
    modernizr: "../components/foundation/js/vendor/custom.modernizr",
    async: "../components/async/lib/async",
    underscore: "../components/underscore/underscore",
    gapi: "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=load",
    foundation:  '../components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation',
    foundationDatePicker: '../components/foundation-datepicker/js/foundation-datepicker',
    ngCookies: '../components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies',
    ngSanitize: '../components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize',
    ngRoute: '../components/angular-route/angular-route',
    services: '../scripts/services',
    fixedservices: '../scripts/fixedservices',
    controllers: '../scripts/controllers',
    filters: '../scripts/filters',
    resources: '../scripts/resources',
    animations: '../scripts/animations',
    directives: '../scripts/directives',
    wtvApp: '../scripts/app',
},
shim: {
    jquery: {
        exports: '$'
    },
    angular: {
      deps: ['jquery'],
      exports: 'angular'
    },
    modernizr: { deps: ['jquery'] },
    async: {
      exports: 'async'
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    },
    foundation: { deps: ['jquery', 'modernizr'] },
    foundation_orbit: { deps: ["foundation"] },
    foundationDatePicker: { deps: ["foundation"] },
    dante: { deps: ["jquery", "underscore", "sanitize"] },
    ngCookies: { deps: ['angular'] },
    ngSanitize: { deps: ['angular'] },
    ngRoute: { deps: ['angular'] },
    ngResource : { deps: ['angular'] },
    ngAnimate : { deps: ['angular'] },
    snap: { deps: ['angular'] },
    ngSnap: { deps: ['angular', 'snap'] },
    wtvApp: { deps: ['angular', 'foundation', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngAnimate' ] },
},
priority: [
    'jquery',
    'angular'
]
});

window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!";

define([
'jquery',
'angular',
'async',
'modernizr',
'underscore',
'gapi',
'wtvApp',
],
function ($, angular, async, modernizr,underscore) {
    'use strict';
    //when everything is loaded run wtvApp
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['wtvApp']);
    });
}
);
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

define('wtvApp',['jquery',
    'angular',
    'async',
    ], function () {

      var wtvApp = angular.module( 'marketApp', [
        'ngRoute', 
        'ngAnimate'
      ]);

      wtvApp.config(
        ['$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider) {

          $locationProvider
            .html5Mode(true)
            .hashPrefix('!');


          $routeProvider 

            //CART
            .when('/cart',{
              templateUrl: 'views/frontdesk/cart.html',
            })
            .when('/card',{
              templateUrl: 'views/frontdesk/card.html',
            })

            //REDIRECT TO HOME
            .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
            });

        }]);

      wtvApp.run(['$route', '$location', '$rootScope', function ($route, $location, $rootScope) {

        $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
          $(document).foundation();
        });

      }])


      return wtvApp;

 });
```

Comment: can you show wtvapp file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved it!!!

```
requirejs: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: 'app/scripts',
      include: ['main.js'],
      out: 'dist/scripts/main.js',
      mainConfigFile: "app/scripts/main.js",
      optimize: "uglify2",
      preserveLicenseComments: false,
      generateSourceMaps: true,
      useStrict: true,
      almond: true,
      wrap: true,
      insertRequire: ['main.js'], // <-- added this
      findNestedDependencies: true
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: wow what a gem I had to add 'main' not 'main.js' and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

After much deliberation I finally found out how to make it work the way that I wanted it to.

```
requirejs:         {
        compile: {
            options: {
                baseUrl:                 '.',
                out:                     distDir + 'js/production.js',
                name:                    bowerDir + 'almond/almond',
                include:                 'main',
                mainConfigFile:          'main.js', // Ensures paths specified in requirejs.config are available
                optimize:                'uglify2', // none / uglify2
                uglify2: {
                    //Example of a specialized config. If you are fine
                    //with the default options, no need to specify
                    //any of these properties.
                    output: {
                        beautify: false // switch to true to see the full output
                    },
                    compress: {
                        sequences: false,
                        global_defs: {
                            DEBUG: false
                        }
                    },
                    warnings: true,
                    mangle: false // THIS is the main culprit as this does mess with angular modules
                },
                preserveLicenseComments: false,
                generateSourceMaps:      true,
                useStrict:               true,
                almond:                  true,
                wrap:                    true,
                insertRequire:           ['main'], // <-- added this
                findNestedDependencies:  true
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You define :

```
angular.module( 'marketApp', [
```

And Bootstrap :

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['wtvApp']);
```

angular.bootstrap take a DOM node and the **name** of your module.
You should do bootstrap as follow :

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['marketApp']);
```

Comment: Ups I didn't correct the name on the last file for posting! Sorry about that, but this is not what causes the app not to bootstrap

Comment: You still have Failed to instantiate module error or is it another one ? If so the name of the module that failed is stil wtvapp or marketApp ?

Comment: The naming isnnot the problem, I just didn't change it before posting here :s it works before using almond, so the namings match up